# dropdown for search suggestions with prompting

Tags: javascript, html, dynamic, input, autosuggest

I have a a script that provides suggestions for an input field based on a user typing a character in the input field.  It uses a function to make suggestions in a comma delimited using this html:

```
<body>
    <form>
        First name:
        <input type="text" onkeyup="showHint(this.value)" size="20" />
    </form>

    <p>Suggestions: <span id="txtHint"></span></p>
</body>
```

Now I want to use a drop down box instead of a suggestion string.  I think I need to put the input field and the selectable options in a div, but I can't figure out how to get a option into the input field after it's been selected.  How do I do that?

Comment: Use jQuery's autocomplete: http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/autocomplete

Answer (score 0):

You could get value attribute (or text node) of the selected option and populate it to input box.

```
$(<input>).value(
    originalValue +", " + $(<select>).val()
);
```

JQuery Autocomplete as @DemianBrecht suggested would be the other way to go, if you are looking to create more feature-complete interface.

Comment: Would it make sense to do all the html formatting in the PHP and substitute the formatted html for the comma delimited text suggestions that the script currently displays?

Comment: @niche - I don't really get what you meant by that.